# I am not able to save comments enter by user to database and retrive it to show on templates

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-views, django-templates

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{hotel.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{hotel.address}}</p>
    <p>{{hotel.city}}</p>
    <p>{{hotel.state}}</p>
    <p>{{hotel.Zip_code}}</p>
    <h2>Comment</h2>
    {% for C in hotel.comment.all %}
        <p>{{ C.comment }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <form action="/hotel/{{hotel.id}}/comment/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="your comment">
        <input  type="submit" value="comment">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

above code is for hotel_details.html where user will put comment and it will save in database and user will also able to see other users comment

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from demo.models import Hotel


def hotel_list(request):
    hotel = Hotel.objects.all()
    context = {
        'hotel': hotel,
    }
    return render(request, 'hotel_list.html',context)

def hotel_details(request,hotel_id):
    hotel=Hotel.objects.get(id=hotel_id)
    context={
        'hotel':hotel,
    }
    return render(request, 'hotel_details.html',context)

# Create your views here.
def comment_on_hotel(request,hotel_id):
    hotel=Hotel.objects.get(id=hotel_id)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment=request.POST['comment']
        hotel.comment += f'\n{comment}'
        hotel.save()
    return render(request, 'hotel_details.html',{'hotel':hotel})
above is views.py 



Models .py 

from django.db import models



# Create your models here.


class Hotel(models.Model):
    
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Zip_code=models.IntegerField()
    comment=models.TextField()

urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from demo import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.hotel_list,name='hotel_list'),
    path('hotel/<int:hotel_id>/',views.hotel_details, name='hotel_details'),
    path('hotel/<int:hotel_id>/comment/',views.comment_on_hotel , name='comment'),
]
please anyone can help why this problem is happening
```

I want that in hotel_details.html page a user should able to enter comment for particular hotel selected by him and it should save in that particular hotel in database .also user should able to see comments enter by other users

Comment: Show us your `comment` model.